# Acomodar Dropdown menu en una celda

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tengo una tabla que se llena mediante busqueda ajax.
Este es el código de la tabla:

```
<table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>CLIENT ID</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>E-mail</th>
                                    <th>City</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                    <th>Register Date</th>
                                    <th>Options</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td style="height: 150px;"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>CLIENT ID</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>E-mail</th>
                                    <th>City</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                    <th>Register Date</th>
                                    <th>Options</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Y esta es la función con la que se llena:

```
public function ajax_listClients()
    {
        $list = $this->clients->get_datatables($this->session->userdata('idOriginatingSubscriber'));
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $clients) {
            /*$no++;*/
            $row = array();
            $options = "";
            /*$row[] = $no;*/
            $row[] = $clients->fcName;
            $row[] = $clients->fnId;
            $row[] = $clients->fcPhone;
            $row[] = $clients->fcEmail;
            $row[] = $clients->fcCity;
            $row[] = $clients->fcState;
            $row[] = date("m/d/Y" , strtotime($clients->fdRegisterDate));

             //Dropdown menu for edit and delete clients

             $row[] = '
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <button style="width:35px; align=left;" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><h3 style="writing-mode:vertical-lr;">...</h3></button>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="'.site_url("C_clients/editClient/".$clients->fnId).'" style="color:black;"><h5>Edit</h5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:deleteClient('.$clients->fnId.')" style="color:black;"><h5>Delete</h5></a>
                             </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'.site_url("C_clients/newContract/".$clients->fnId).'" style="color:black;"><h5>Add Contract</h5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>';


            $data[] = $row;

        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->clients->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->clients->count_filtered($this->session->userdata('idOriginatingSubscriber')),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Mi problema es que no se ve todo el dropdown menu cuando doy click al boto, cómo se ve en la imagen:
[image: Tabla donde el dropdown menu no se ve]

Comment: No estás cerrando la etiqueta `h5`, puede que sea por eso. No cierras aquí: **`<h5>Edit</h5`**, tampoco aquí: **`<h5>Add Contract</h5`**

Comment: ya se ve media parte del Edit pero no se ve completo el dropdown.

Comment: ¿Qué significa que no se ve completo? ¿Que faltan opciones (son sólo tres)? ¿Corregiste los cierres de `h5`? Si se ven todos los `li` que tienes, pero cortados, ya ese es un problema de tu CSS.

Comment: Osea son 3 opciones, solo se ve la primero y a medias, en otra tabla tengo el mismo menú pero esa la llené diferente, y ambos menús estan bootstrapeados

Comment: Cambia las tres opciones por algo simple a ver qué pasa: `<li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>` y di si se muestran o no. Si no se muestran debe ser un problema de tu CSS o de Bootstrap.